# Can Castle.Windsor pick constructors using types and names?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I have a `class`.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string a, string b)
    {
    }

    public Foo(string a, byte[] b)
    {
    }
}
```

I am trying to register `Foo` and use the `public Foo(string a, string b)` constructor. However, Windsor will not look at the type of the values being passed in and chooses the wrong constructor.

Program:

```
class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<Foo>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("a", "Bar"))
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("b", "Baz")));

        // Blows up trying to convert string to byte[]
        var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
    }
}
```

How can I help Windsor to choose the right constructor?

Note in my real code I am trying to pull values from the `App.Config` using `Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue`.

Edit:

I solved this by creating a wrapper class that invoked the proper constructor.

```
public class FooInjectionWrapper
{
    public FooInjectionWrapper(string a, string b)
    {
        Foo = new Foo(a, b);
    }

    public Foo Foo { get; private set; }
}
```

Program:

```
class Program
{
    public void Main()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<FooInjectionWrapper>()
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("a", "Bar"))
            .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("b", "Baz")));
        container.Register(Component.For<Foo>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(k => k.Resolve<FooInjectionWrapper>().Foo));

        //Works fine
        var foo = container.Resolve<Foo>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your components should only contain one (injection) constructor. Having [multiple constructors is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Comment: @Steven It's library code that is external from my project. A proper DI container should be able to cope regardless.

Comment: Every container can cope. Read the article: don't use auto-wiring on library types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windsor doesn't provide support for choosing a constructor. Windsor (and other containers) consider all constructors to be equal. If everything is equal, the more dependencies a component has, the more capabilities it is supposed to have. That's why windsor will pick the greediest constructor. If that's equal, it'll pick just any constructor: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.How-constructor-is-selected.ashx

A work-around would be using a factory-method:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<Foo>()
             .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new Foo("Bar", "Baz")));
```

Comment: I ended up using a wrapper to workaround Windsor. This behavior is inconvenient.

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to define a value for the string type instead of the "b" parameter. Naming takes precedence over the type so the "a" parameter can be defined and the string type can be defined in parallel:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Component.For<Foo>()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("a", "Bar"))
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue(typeof(string), "Baz")));
```

Comment: This is a good workaround (+1), but `Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue` does not provide an overload for type specification.

Comment: argh, didn't realize that the AppSettings dependency didn't have the overload. Will keep looking into it, though